# How do I set the selected value in an ASP.NET Drop Down List?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using an ASP.NET dropdown. I want to set the selected element using an ID (`Id`) which is stored in the `DataValue` field.

```
ddlTest.DataValueField = "Id";    
ddlTest.DataTextField = "Name";
ddlTest.DataSource = searchResultList;
ddlTest.DataBind();
```

But all I can see is the `SelectedIndex` property which isn't the correct thing. How do I set by value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After it's bound you can set the SelectedValue property to the correct id.

Answer (score 1):

ddlTest.selectedValue = [whatever value you want to set];

Answer (score 0):

If you need the text of the selected item then you can use

```
dropdwonlistID.SelectedItem.Value // selecting value of the selected item
dropdwonlistID.SelectedItem.Text // selecting displayed text of the selected item
```